# Expandable Listview with Listview and Custom Adapters

Tags: android, listview, fragment, custom-adapter, expandable

the PRJ contains :
Frag_Settings which has the ExpandableListView, using a custom adpater I name it **Frag_Settings_Adapter** listAdapter.

the expandable groups are 5 and are static (aka predefined). Each of group accommodate a different view. One of these views has listview, which also implements a custom adapter (takes records from dbase)...

so lets see, what I have wrote for the moment, at expandable **Frag_Settings_Adapter** :

```
@Override

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

switch (groupPosition) {
case 0:
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings_row_detail_01_cities, null);
    break;
case 1:
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings_row_detail_02_categories, null);

    //raise event to parent
    if (listener_02_categories != null)
        listener_02_categories.fill_with_data(convertView);
    break;
}

return convertView;
}
```

when group is 2, inflate the view + raise an event to fragment **with the view!** (is this good?)

then at fragment, **onActivityCreated**, when setup **expandable_listview** :

```
listAdapter = new Frag_Settings_Adapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

listAdapter.setListener(new Fill_02_Categories_Listener() {

    @Override
    public void fill_with_data(View convertView) {

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////listview 02 - categories
        lstv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.frag_settings_row_detail_categories_lstv);
        Frag_Settings_Categories_LIST = new ArrayList<Frag_Settings_Categories>();
        lstv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lstv_adapter = new Frag_Settings_Categories_Adapter(getActivity(), Frag_Settings_Categories_LIST);
        lstv.setAdapter(lstv_adapter);

        CategoriesDatasource categories_datasource = new CategoriesDatasource(getActivity());

        for (Categories d : categories_datasource.getAllCategoriess()) {
            Frag_Settings_Categories_LIST.add(new Frag_Settings_Categories(d.getid(),d.getcategory_name(),false));
        }

        lstv.setAdapter(lstv_adapter);

    }
});

// setting list adapter
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

-this one working but I have somehow increase the height of expandable group 2 because now I can see only 1listview item... :(

-over all, is there any way to achieve this in more easier way?

-the method I follow is correct?

Answer (score 0):

No way^ too many problems with that way....

I discover a manual solution, once as I said the views are static [https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/android-tips-expandablecollapsible-views](https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/android-tips-expandablecollapsible-views/)/